# How to show a column with the value Zero in Column chart in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, stacked

Which I am passing to:

```
       series: [{
                        name: 'Fixed bugs',
                        data: fixed,
                        pointWidth: 40
                    }, {
                        name: 'Assigned Bugs',
                        data:assigned,
                        pointWidth: 40
                    }, {
                        name: 'Re-Opened Bugs',
                        data: Reopened,
                        pointWidth: 40
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Closed Bugs',
                        data: closed,
                        pointWidth: 40
                    }]
```

to [this chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked/gray) and I have the data like this :

```
     data: fixed=[3,5,5,8]
    data:assigned=[0,1,0,0]
```

and follows. Now I want to show the column with zero value to... For me its not showing the column value with zero.

Comment: If it is zero then there should be no height to the column. If the value is zero - do you just want to show that it is zero? Kind of confused as to what you want it to look like.

Comment: @wergeld yes i want to show that cloumn is zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it - although I think just having the column be zero-valued and not visible is the best way.

Find a very very low number that none of your data points would ever have but still keep it >0. Let us say it is .005. When you bring in your data any value that is 0 assign it this .005 value. In your tooltip formatter do an IF on the value. If it is .005 then make it 0. This way you get to see the "zero" column but the tooltip displayed will be 0 as well. If you are doing any kind of calculation on the stacked columns then you need to account for this non-0 0 value in there as well.

Comment: a nice explanation and a nice answer...i will try this ty

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. It should be **desired login**'s or **Thilaga**'s answer. Please just use `minPointLength`

Answer (score 42):

minPointLength will work. Use this.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
    minPointLength: 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do this quite simply with the `minPointLength` option. It sets the minimum number of pixels per column, default is 0, so zero values don't show up. It's in the docs [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.minPointLength).

Try [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsEEJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to display, but maybe you could try to show the datalabels like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'gray'
        }
    }
}
```

[Attempt at demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6UMnK/)

Comment: @Qyvindk i want to display the zero column if the column has the value zero

Comment: I'm no expert in graph theory, but wouldn't that imply that the column has a value greater or less than zero? Maybe you could draw a sketch showing how you want the chart to look?